# MongoDB Concurrency problems in cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, concurrency, pm2

I came to a point where I definetely need to scale my application and unfortunately I have never thought about clustering when I wrote my application. Now I've got a couple problems and I am not sure what one would do to avoid such problems. I will show two fairly easy code examples:

**Example 1:**

If I would run this function on 8 instances it would probably select the same profiles over and over again (because they are ordered). It makes sense to update those profiles which haven't been updated for a very long time, but is there some kind of "lock" which would prevent the other instances from working on the exact same documents?

```
// Select 100 least updated profiles and update them
PlayerProfile.find().sort({ updated_at: 1 }).limit(100).then((playerProfiles) => {
  // Code which would update these 100 selected profiles
})
```

**Example 2:**

I have a collection in my mongodb with 1000 accounts and each instance should take 100 accounts. No instance is allowed to use the exact same account credentials. How could I make sure that this is the case when running multiple instances?

```
Account.find({}, 'player_id token').limit(this.clientQuantity).then((accounts) => {
      logger.info(`Using ${accounts.length} accounts from the database`)
      for (let i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        const accountCredentials = accounts[i].toObject()
      }
})
```

**Question**

What would be good ways to solve the issues introduced with the above two examples?

Comment: What do you think you mean here? These are just `.find()` queries so it's unclear as to what you could possibly perceive the problem to be. Do you have code "inside these" performing updates? If so, then you really should not, and should be instead issuing atomic update operations. There is no such thing as a concurrency problem with selecting data.

Comment: @NeilLunn I think I explained it in the example 1 text. I am seleting the oldest 100 profiles to update them (for example I need to update one of the PlayerProfile's fields). If I would do this on all 8 instances they would all select the same 100 oldest profiles and work on the exact same profiles. This is what I want to avoid

Comment: A well explained question is not one day old without an answer. Learn from the feedback rather than choosing to ignore it.